# Python Error when I import CSV file into Cassandra workspace

Tags: python, import, cassandra

I'm using an Oracle database and I just started to use Cassandra. I started with a basic task like export/import CSV files. It works fine in my interaction env, but stall in production env. Here is the error:

> Process ImportProcess-1:Traceback (most recent call last):  File
>   "/usr/lib64/python2.6/multiprocessing/process.py", line 232, ... ...
>   Unable to connect to any servers', {'AQPLCS08': error('unpack requires
>   a string argument of length 4

I execute the import command like this:

```
cqlsh AQILCS01 -e "COPY ks_mdm.prueba_alarmas from '/tmp/datos_alarmas.csv'"
```

I look at the web for a workaround, but I didn't find any information.
Does anyone know?

Comment: Hi Luis, welcome to SO - could you please provide a code sample to show what exactly you are trying. Furthermore some information about your environment (which python version and which library you are using) would be helpful.

Comment: Hello ! Yes sure. The command line I use was: EXPORT: cqlsh AQPLCS08 -e "COPY ks_mdm.alarmas to '/tmp/datos_alarmas.csv'"


IMPORT: cqlsh AQILCS01 -e "COPY ks_mdm.prueba_alarmas from '/tmp/datos_alarmas.csv'"

Comment: Can I send a attach file? I have an excel with all the RPM from INT (OK) and PRO(KO)

Comment: Are you able to connect using  `cqlsh AQILCS01`?

Comment: Are you using UDTs in your data model?  Can you post your table definition and a sample of the CSV file?

Comment: Hello. yes I can connect if I cqlsh AQILCS01

Comment: Hello, here is one of the definition of a table :

Answer (score 0):

here is the definition:

```
 describe datos_alarmas_2;

CREATE TABLE ks_mdm.datos_alarmas_2 (
    device text PRIMARY KEY,
    valor text
) WITH bloom_filter_fp_chance = 1.0
    AND caching = '{"keys":"ALL", "rows_per_partition":"NONE"}'
    AND comment = ''
    AND compaction = {'min_threshold': '4', 'class': 'org.apache.cassandra.db.compaction.SizeTieredCompactionStrategy', 'max_threshold': '32'}
    AND compression = {'sstable_compression': 'org.apache.cassandra.io.compress.LZ4Compressor'}
    AND dclocal_read_repair_chance = 0.0
    AND default_time_to_live = 0
    AND gc_grace_seconds = 7200
    AND max_index_interval = 2048
    AND memtable_flush_period_in_ms = 0
    AND min_index_interval = 128
    AND read_repair_chance = 0.1
    AND speculative_retry = '99.0PERCENTILE';
```